# HTML Form + PHP + MYSQL 500 Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am receiving an internal 500 error when trying to insert data from HTML form into MySQL database via PHP. I am hosting a site with an Apache 2 webserver on an Ubuntu server (droplet using DigitalOcean). PHP and MySQL are both installed on the server. HTML below and PHP below. I have tested with a PHP echo with the variable $name, which was successful, but I am thrown the error whenever I try to connect to mysql. I know 500 is an internal error, but am not sure where to go from here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>who this</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STYLE.css">
</head>


<body>
    <h1 id="header2">me</ h1>

    <div id="back">
            <a href="/index.html">back</a>
    </div>

    <div id="me-intro">
        <p>tell me about yourself</p>
    </div>

    <div id="joke">
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <div id="one">
            <p>name: <input type="text" name="name" id='first'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <p>gender: <input type="text" name="gender" id='second'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="three">
            <p>age: <input type="text" name = "age" id='third'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="four">
            <p>occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" id='fourth'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="five">
            <p>education: <input type="text" name="education" id='fifth'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="six">
            <p>car you drive: <input type="text" name="car" id='sixth'></p>
        </div>
        <div id="seven">
            <p>phone number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="seventh"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="eight">
            <p>address: <input type="text" name="address" id="eighth"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="nine">
            <p>social security number: <input type="text" name="ssn" id="ninth">
        </div>
        <div id="ten">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

process.php below

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password_here", "database_here");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$occupation = $_POST["occupation"];
$education = $_POST["education"];
$car = $_POST["car"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$ssn = $_POST["ssn"];

if($conn -> connect_error) {
    die("err: dis not working: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_here (name, gender, age, occupation, education, car, phone, address, ssn) VALUES ('$name', '$gender', '$age', '$occupation', '$education', '$car', '$phone', '$address', '$ssn')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error: did not submit form to mysql";     
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: In a browser could you open the developer console, go to the network tab, clear the console if anything is already there, then submit your form. You should see the  `process.php` POST call. Click on it, then let us know what's in the response.

Comment: Could it be this code `$conn -> connect_error` You have spaces before and after ->.

Comment: @aynber looked in the logs and saw 
`[Wed Jul 18 16:41:41.228261 2018] [:error] [pid 12164] [client 96.9.86.19:52086] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/calebcarithers.com/public_html/process.php on line 28, referer: https://calebcarithers.com/me.php`
Took out the final else statement in process.php and all is working! Also, thanks, will look into prepared statements.